# C# - Multiple timers in Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, windows-services

I just start develop a windows service. But I'm not sure if I can use multiple timers in `Onstart()` method?

```js
private System.Timers.Timer timer1;
private System.Timers.Timer timer2;


        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);  // every 30 seconds
            this.timer1.AutoReset = true;
            this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fonction1);
            this.timer1.Start();
          
          
          this.timer2 = new System.Timers.Timer(10 * 60 * 1000); // every 10 minutes
            this.timer2.AutoReset = true;
            this.timer2.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fonction2);
            this.timer2.Start();
          
          
        }


       private void fonction1(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            bla bla
        }

       private void fonction2(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            bla bla
        }
```

`fonction1` and `fonction2` run at the same time but they don't have the same interval of running. Their subsequent start times don't need to be in sync.In this case,

1. Can I use 2 timers in `OnStart()` method?
2. And if so, does `fonction1` which typically run every 30 seconds have to wait the end of `fonction2` to the next start?

I need to run these 2 methods with different intervals in a same Windows Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the reason why not. `System.Timers.Timer` raise an event in the separate thread from `ThreadPool` so they are independent from each other. The only thing you need to make sure that code in your callback will not be executing  longer than the `Interval`. If you think it may happen, you need to stop timer in the event handler and recreate it in the end.

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer1;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(30000) { AutoReset = false };
    this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
    this.timer1.Start(); 
}

private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        // Do Work
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        // Logging
    }
    finally 
    {
        timer1.Start()
    }
}
```

> If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  you can use any number of timers - they are absolutely independent